# How to create microsecond timer interval in linux?

Tags: linux, timer, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I want to create an accurate 50 usec interrupt-based timer in Linux using c and c++.is there any standard method?

Comment: Please specify what programming language yoou are using.

Comment: Accurate? Kernel is not so fast (or not so slow by allowing such things, depending the point of view)

Comment: You would need to use the hrtimer interface. It is possible (or very likely) that you will miss some timeout events (the Linux kernel is not an RTOS kernel), but at least you should be able to tell how much time has passed with a reasonable amount of precision.

Comment: That means usec timer is not properly work on linux ?

Comment: Linux is not a real-time OS. It will never be as accurate or precise as a RTOS.